# The meaning of 'That's tellin's,'

Tags: meaning

> 'Sorry! It's all right,' said Una, rubbing her nose. 'How many rabbits
>   did you get today?'
>
> **'That's tellin's,'** the old man grinned as he re-hoisted his faggot. 'I reckon Mus' Ridley he've got rheumatism along o' lyin' in
>   the dik to see I didn't snap up any. Think o' that now!'
>
> They laughed a good deal while he told them the tale.

This is from "The Tree of Justice" in "Rewars and Fairies" by Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning below.
'That's tellin's' "
Is this mean 'I have got many rabbits'?

I ma glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

You slightly mis-transcribed your quotation.

**That's tellin'** is dialect for **That's telling,** with **telling** used in the sense of disclosing that which is moral or prudent to keep secret. When one sibling **tells on** an other sibling to their parents, that is a great sin of childhood. The old man is refusing to speak while giving a motive that will seem reasonable to children.